# Enviar array desde Angular a una WebApi C#

Tags: c#, array, angular

Tengo un objeto en Angular, que dentro tiene un array de elementos.

```
export interface LugarInterface {


idLugar: number;

areas?:Array<AreaInterface>;
```

Entonces recorro el html y agrego a ese array objetos AreaInterface, y luego se lo mando a la webapi que declaro así la clase

```
 List<L_Area> area = new List<L_Area>();
```

Cuando debugueo y veo que recibe el controller llega vacío, los datos que se envían son:

```
{"idLugar":0,"areas":[{"IdArea":0,"NombreArea":"Area1"},{"IdArea":0,"NombreArea":"Area2"}]}
```

Pero al debuguear como decía llega el array de arreas vacíos, alguien sabe como pasar este array a la webapi? gracias

Comment: como esta definido en la api?

Comment: asi List<L_Area> areas = new List<L_Area>();

Comment: No. Eso crea una lista. Yo te estoy preguntando como definis los datos que recibis en tu api. Cual es la firma de la funcion?